# axios request header Authorization .net web api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, request-headers

```
axios.get("https://localhost:7179/GetFavorite/15", 
          {headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${token}} },)
     .then(response => { console.log(response.data); });
```

Header:

```
KeyValuePair2;KeyValuePair2.key;KeyValuePair`2.Key 
"[Accept, /]";Accept;Accept
"[Host, localhost:7179]";Host;Host
"[User-Agent, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36]";User-Agent;User-Agent
"[Accept-Encoding, gzip, deflate, br]";Accept-Encoding;Accept-Encoding
"[Accept-Language, en-US,en;q=0.9,az-AZ;q=0.8,az;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,tr;q=0.4]";Accept-Language;Accept-Language
"[Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization]";
```

In postman

```
[Authorization, Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiWWVuaSBNZWthbiIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6Ikt1cnMiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6IjE1IiwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMzM4ODg0fQ.gWAT3fDIZRzRs5MxyTjNdupR0V6aTSgKrNKFVMJSN5gn1GmrZzgiIdixf_Y4UNtxKYsMXk-Rvhs63zeTdu0m1A]";Authorization;Authorization
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7179/GetFavorite/15' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:7002' that is not equal to the supplied origin.